# Trying to scan a image through pytesseract for a number sequence

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm a python beginner and i'm trying to scan some images with pytesseract for a number sequence (i'm on google colab). I need scan the images and convert it to string.

[CodeLinesPrint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXSdJ.png)

Comment: Please don't  post images of code or errors; see [ask].

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: did you read error message? It shows that it can't find tesseract - `PyTesseract` is only python wrapper on C/C++ program `Tesseract` which you have to download and install separatelly (not using `pip` but rather `apt`). And if you have installed `Tesseract` then it may need `/full/path/to/tesseract` in one of command.

Answer (score 0):

`PyTesseract` is only Python wrapper on C/C++ program `Tesseract` which you have to install

```
apt install tesseract
```

`pip` is only for python modules, `apt` is for other programs.